# Issue installing twarc2 in conda environment

Tags: python, conda, twarc2

I'm trying to install `twarc2` in my `conda` environment (from [here](https://anaconda.org/brown-data-science/twarc)) :

```
conda install -c brown-data-science twarc
```

The above command runs fine, if I try it again I get `All requested packages already installed.`

However when I try to import the module in python:

```
>>> import twarc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twarc'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is now [available through Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/twarc).

```
conda create -n twarc -c conda-forge python=3.10 twarc
```

This provides v2.12.0 of the PyPI package, which includes both `twarc` and `twarc2` entrypoints.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pay attention to the fact that the version of `twarc` from anaconda that I was installing is only for python2 (and not twarc2). As a result it was installed for python2, and I was trying to import the module in python3.

The correct way to install `twarc2` in a `conda` environment is as follows:

```
conda create -n twarc2 python=3.10
conda activate twarc2
pip install --upgrade twarc
```